# Algorithm for cleaning some spots on a floor using automatic vacuum cleaners?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

Please feel free to rename the question...

Here's the problem:

I have a certain number 'n' of automatic vacuum cleaners on a floor with a number 'k' of dirty spots on it. What's the optimal way to assign the vacuum cleaner to the dirty spots in order to clean the floor in the most efficient way?

Details:

- The floor is represented by a not weighted graph with n/k randomly placed on it
- At most one vacuum cleaner can be assigned to a dirty spot
- Ignore the possibility that two vacuum cleaners might hit each other
- The time for cleaning a spot is not relevant. Only the distance between them it is
- Keep in mind that k might be greater than n

What "kind" of problem is this?

How would you implement a solution for it?

I thought about calculating the distance between all the possible pairs ('n' * 'k'), ordering them in ascending order, and matching vacuum cleaners and dirty spots making sure not to send two cleaners to the same spot. This might not be efficient and it probably doesn't find the best solution at all times..

Thanks!

Comment: Define 'efficient'. That is, what's your _fitness function_? For example: is it minimum total travel distance for all cleaners?

Comment: Yes, performances can be calculated considering the travel distance of the cleaners (they all have same speed). `The floor has to be clean and the task is over`. As you said -minimum total travel distance for all cleaners- should be a correct and more formal description of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the [travelling salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) problem to me. but I'm sure there are faster ways to get a result close to the optimal solution.

Hopefully this gives you something to start searching with.

Comment: i hope it doesn't look like that, that problem is hard! ;) If we consider 'n'=1 cleaner and 'k' spots to clean you might be right but since I could also have 'n' > 'k' here things seem pretty different. I'm still trying to understand if having 'multiple salesman' makes the problem harder or easier... thanks!

Comment: I think it's not quite TSP, but possibly related, since you have _k_ 'towns' to be visited by _n_ 'salesmen'. So we can think of it as _n_ TSPs (possibly conducted in parallel). That's one avenue to pursue: assume that for any given cleaner its optimal route will include only those spots closest to it and necessarily exclude spots closer to another cleaner (unless someone can find a counter-example). So we can divide & conquer the larger graph into _n_ smaller graphs.

Comment: Easy counterexample re "include only those spots closest to it":  n=3 cleaners, on x-axis at x=5,10,15; k=12 spots, at x=1..4,6..9,11..14.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is known in literature as Multiple Traveling Salesman Problem (MTSP).

**[TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)** is a hard problem to solve, in fact a brute force solution can be found only for a small number of cities (<~20). Many heuristic methods have been developed in order to find a suboptimal solution: you can find an intresting survay in [this paper](http://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs/12736/InTech-Traveling_salesman_problem_an_overview_of_applications_formulations_and_solution_approaches.pdf). In general I find a good solution the application of a ***Closest neighbor heuristic*** followed by a ***k-opt*** optimization in a ***Hill climbing*** with ***random restarts***.

I strongly reccomend you to implement TSP as a starting point for your algorithm (k=1), it's just a brick that you will use later in the solution of the MTSP and will give you the opportunity to test your skills in an heuristic approach. Furthermore, once you understand the theory, the implementation will require just an evening (maybe with some cup of coffee by your side).

**Multiple Traveling Salesman Problem** is a really challenging problem but you can apply the same heuristic methods. Basically you need to find an initial solution in which you assign a number of cities to each salesman (see later for a possibly *Closest neighbor* metric), than for each salesman you can compute an heuristic solution of the TSP.

**Hill climbing** methods here can swap cities between salesman and recompute TSP. This method will lead you to many [local minima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima), for this reason i suggest you to use a [**simulated annealing algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing). Basically you swap the cities with a decreasing probability during the evolution of the algorithm.

**An initial solution for MTSP**
Look at this one dimension example (S for salesman an C fo city)

- S0 = 3
- S1 = 5
- C0 = 2.5
- C1 = 1.5
- C2 = 3.6
- C3 = 8

Just implement a greedy algorithm (use a timeline with a queue)

1. Time 0.5: S0 -> C0
2. Time 1.4: S1 -> C2
3. Time 1.5: S0 -> C1
4. Time 5.8: S1 -> C3

Initial partion: S0:{C0,C1} - S0:{C2,C3}

You can also read this article and follow the bibliography backwards

http://www.worldacademicunion.com/journal/1749-3889-3897IJNS/IJNSVol09No2Paper06.pdf